# Fixed point property with given topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a non degenerate set. Fix $a\in X.$ Define  $$T_{inc,a}=\{\emptyset\}\cup \{A\subset X\colon a\in A\}$$ It is easy to see $(X,T_{inc,a})$ is a topological space.

**Example** let $a\in X$ and  $f$ be a continuous function from $(X,T_{inc,a})$ to itself. Show $f$ has a fixed point property.
**Proof**,
Recall that $f$ has a fixed point property means there $x\in X$ such that $f(x)=x$. By way of contradiction, assume there is no $x\in X$ such that $f(x)=x.$ In particular, $f(a)\neq a$ so $a\not\in\{f(a)\}.$ By the definition of $T_{inc,a}$,  $\{f(a)\}$ is closed set. Since $f$ is a continuous function $f^{-1}(f(a))$ is closed set and contains $a.$ Thus, $f^{-1}(f(a))=X$  which implies to $f(X)=\{f(a)\}.$ Hence, take $x=f(a)$ is our fixed point . $f(f(a))=f(a).$

I think, there is something wrong in my proof since I was supposed to get a contradiction.  Could please tell what I did wrong. I do not think that it would be true if f is not a continuous function. Right?

Comment: You do not need to do it by contradiction.  If $f(a)=a$, you're done.  If not, do your argument.  Then $f$ must be constant to the value $f(a) =b$, so $b$ is a fixed point.  In other words, you DID get a contradiction:  you said there were no fixed points, but $b$ is fixed.

Comment: @Randall, Is not true without $f$ is continuous . Right?

Comment: Of course not.  Why would it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up the structure of the proof a bit differently and you're good to go:

Let $f: X \to X$ be continuous.
If $f(a)=a$, you're done: $a$ is a fixpoint.
Otherwise $f^{-1}[\{f(a)\}]$ is closed (as the inverse image of a closed set; here we use continuity), and non-empty as it contains $a$  (using your own argument), and so $f^{-1}[\{f(a)\}]=X$ by the definition of the topology. Hence in that case $f(x)=f(a)$ for all $x \in X$ and $b:=f(a)$ is a fixpoint of $f$. QED.

For a non-continuous function we could have any function $f: X \to X$ and we would not always have a fixpoint (unless $X$ is a singleton of course).